# How to use inputs with a variable shape or dimensions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

I'm new to TensorFlow and I have to implement a model that has a lot of images as input. But these images don't have the same dimensions, so when I transform them into arrays, they don't have the same dimension.

I wonder how to declare the weights without a predefined shape.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([?, ?]))
```

Comment: I think you have to either need to re-size images or use different pooling like Pyramid Pooling

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't feed images inside a Variable. Probably what you need is a Placeholder (kind of variable that you can use to be fed with data at some point of your algorithm). See this link for more info: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder

But also in the case of Placeholders, you must specify dimensions. So that my advice is to use some tecnique to resize all you pictures to the same dimension (see padding, mirroring,... for example): of course, only if this is allowed for your specific problem.

Just in some cases you can leave some dimesion not specified, for example if you want to define a neural network, you can leave batch_size not defined like this

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28))
```

If you are to implement your first neural network, I strongly advice to have a look here. It's the most simple and clear guide to tensorflow, from the official website: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners
It worth the reading :)

Comment: I'll tf.Variable for weights and biases. But the problem is the same (I suppose). It's not my first neural network, but is the first time I have such complication. I might reshape the image vector to only one dimension, what do you think?